# ConTeXt LMTX: How to use the RSFS font?

Tags: context

I try to use RSFS font with ConTeXt LMTX (2022.09.11 20:44) and get nowhere.

From [the wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Rsfs):

```tex
\starttypescript [math] [modern,computer-modern,latin-modern,ams] [size]
     \definebodyfont [17.3pt,14.4pt,12pt,11pt,10pt,9pt][mm][mc=rsfs10 sa 1]
     \definebodyfont [8pt,7pt] [mm] [mc=rsfs7 sa 1]
     \definebodyfont [6pt,5pt,4pt] [mm] [mc=rsfs5 sa 1]
\stoptypescript

\definefamilysynonym [default] [scriptfamily] [mc]

\def\scr{\fam\purefamily{scriptfamily}} % To use ${\scr ABC}$
\def\script#1{{\scr#1}}                 % To use $\script{ABC}$

\definetypeface [modern] [mm] [math] [modern] [ams] [encoding=texnansi]

\setupbodyfont[reset,modern,11pt]

\starttext

${\scr ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\sum_{\scr ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\stoptext
```

I get this compilation error

```
tex error       > tex error on line 7 in file ./main.tex: Undefined control sequence \undefined

<line 3.7>
    \definefamilysynonym
     [default] [scriptfamily] [mc]

...

 7 >>  \definefamilysynonym [default] [scriptfamily] [mc]

...

The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. You can just continue as I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

From this [SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507212/213111) I get the following error:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 35 in file ./main.tex: Undefined control sequence \undefined

<line 3.35>
    \newfam
    \calfam

...

35 >>  \newfam\calfam

...

The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. You can just continue as I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

I checked and I could not find any newer resources on the font use in ConTeXt LMTX.

What do I need to get the RSFS font to my document?

Comment: It might be possible to get it to work with the rsfs type1 font. But we are looking into converting the font into a small opentype font, with only the `uppercasescript` range covered (almost done). We will then be able to configure latin modern (and perhaps also other fonts) so that `\mathcal` uses the built-in script alphabet and `\mathscr` uses the new rsfs font.